# How to Select a drop down value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

i have the following jQuery code inside my razor view:-

```
 $.each(CSData, function (index, itemData) {

                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: itemData.Value,
                        text: itemData.Text
                    }));

                });
```

which populate a drop down list. but how i can check if the current itemData.Value equals certain Model value , and select its value  if so. somthing such as :-

```
if(itemData.Value == @Model.ID).attr('selected', true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the value of the select after creating it:

```
$.each(CSData, function (index, itemData) {
    select.append($('<option/>', {
        value: itemData.Value,
        text: itemData.Text
    }));
});
select.val('@Model.ID');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this stuff after the dropdown-list bound,

```
if(itemData.Value == @Model.ID)
{
   $("#dropdownID option[value='" + itemData.value +"']").attr("selected","selected"); // .prop('selected','selected')
}
```

This way your function should look like this:

```
$.each(CSData, function (index, itemData) {
   select.append($('<option/>', {
        value: itemData.Value,
        text: itemData.Text
    }));
    if(itemData.Value == @Model.ID)
    {
        $("#dropdownID option[value='" + itemData.Value +"']").attr("selected","selected");  // .prop('selected','selected')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if(itemData.Value == @Html.Raw(Model.ID)).attr('selected', true);
```

or put quotes around it if needed:

```
if(itemData.Value == @Html.Raw("'" + Model.ID + "'")).attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// let's assume the following data
var CSData = {
  "itemA": "foo a",
  "itemB": "foo b",
  "itemC": "foo c"
};

// let's assume this as the select element
var select = $("#fooData");

// let's append the CSData to the select
$.each(CSData, function (index, itemData) {

   // first solve how you append the select element
   select
       .append($("<option></option>")
       .attr("value", index)
       .text(itemData));

   if(itemData.Value == @Model.ID){
        // matched, do whatever here
   }

});
```